# convert a file object into a string

Tags: meson-build

In a meson.build file, I have some file define by :

```
 file = files("my_filename.ext")
```

To build an ID, I have try to write :

```
 myTgt = "_other_ext" + file[0][0]
```

And then I have this error :

```
 meson.build:257:4: ERROR:  Invalid use of addition: must be str, not File
```

How can I convert the file object into a valid string ?
(I have try to add .string(), but it's not the solution)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fs` module to extract the name, or since v1.4.0 there is also `.full_path()` function on the `file` object.

Example:

```hs
λ cat meson.build
project('foo', ['c'], version : '1.1')

f = files('meson.build')

fs = import('fs')

message('filename is '  + fs.name(f))
message('path is '      + fs.parent(f))
message('full path is ' + f[0].full_path()) # since v1.4.0
λ meson setup build
[…]
Message: filename is meson.build
Message: path is .
Message: full path is /tmp/foo/meson.build
[…]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution with [format](http://mesonbuild.com/Syntax.html#string-formatting) function:

```
fmt = "_other_ext_@0@"
myTgt = fmt.format(file[0][0])
```